# Not able to configure azure cli on window 2003 server

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, azure, migration, azure-cli

Can anyone help me on this,
I am trying to install and configure azure powershell on my window 2003 aws ec2 instance.
But i am getting error like it is not a valid win32 application.

Comment: Windows 2003 is entirely obsolete at this point. Are you sure it’s even compatible with the Azure PowerShell module?

Comment: You should have decommissioned Windows 2003 several years ago. It is far too old to continue using without truly extraordinary circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Azure PowerShell requires WMF 5.1 ([proof](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.5.0)). Windows Server 2003 supports only WMF 2.0 ([proof](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/compatibility)). So, you cannot run it on Server 2003